# Как в WordPress прикрепить к посту несколько изображений без плагина?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня такой вопрос.

Делаю сайт на Wordpress (первый раз).

Нужно сделать отдельный шаблон для поста, и таким образом чтоб я мог просто прикрепить к посту необходимые изображения. А выводить эти изображения я хочу отдельной версткой.

Никак не пойму как это сделать.

Спасибо!!!

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

Без плагина или соответствующего ему программирования получится довольно неудобно. Например, вы можете использовать медиабиблиотеку (кнопку «Добавить медиафайл») для загрузки файлов в пост, но не вставлять их в поле редактора, чтобы избежать их вывода. В этом случае они всё равно будут загружены, зарегистрированы в базе данных в виде аттачей (постов с параметром 'post_type' = 'attachment') и связаны с вашим родительским постом (за счёт свойства 'post_parent').

Для того, чтобы вывести их в произвольном месте, вам нужно будет написать нечто вроде.

```
$attachments = get_posts( array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
) );

if ( ! empty ( $attachments ) ) :
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) : 
         echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Справка по функции `wp_get_attachment_image()` есть [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image).

Но вообще, лучше всё-таки делать такие вещи с помощью произвольных полей. Пусть даже с плагином, типа ACF. Это будет более адекватный и удобный интерфейс. В плагинах от надёжных разработчиков нет ничего особенно страшного. Даже производительность не слишком пострадает.

Comment: Просто я хочу сделать сам..., так интереснее )))

Comment: @MagBLack если хотите делать самостоятельно, то такая задача чаще всего решается созданием `custom fields`, в которых будет храниться инфа о дополнительно загруженных изображениях

Comment: А как примерно это сделать с помощью custom fields